# The program is to ask for an int and then return that same number

Tags: c#

In C# if I enter 20 it returns 50 but there no math equation in where the declared int should be changed. I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Here is the code.

```
namespace Lab1
{
    class Turtle
    {
         private int weight;

        public int Weight
        {
            get { return weight; }
            set { weight = value; }
        }

         public int getWeight()
         {
             return weight;
         }
        public Turtle(int wgt)
        {
            weight = wgt;
        }

        public void PrintVitals()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Weight: {0}", weight);
        }

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Turtle's Weight: ");
                int wgt = Console.Read();

                Turtle turt = new Turtle(wgt);
                Console.Write(turt.getWeight());

                Console.WriteLine("\nPres Any Key To End");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.Read does not return what you think it does.  Have you stepped through your program with a debugger?  That would almost certainly tell where the expected behavior deviates from the actual behavior.  If you go line by line and check the result of every function, you will find the problem very quickly. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx and http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: After figuring out where the problem is with a debugger, a better question might be "Why does Console.Read() return a value of 50 when I type "20" into the console?"

Answer (score 2):

Console.Read returns an integer representing the ascii of the pressed character.  However, 20 is valid ascii. 2 in ascii is 50.  Because you are using Read and not ReadLine read executes when you press 2 whether you pressed 0 next or not.  It is converting the ascii for 2 to an integer thus "2" becomes 50.

To fix that, parse your console.ReadLine to an integer via,

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
int wgt = int.Parse(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

edit:

Sorry, as per MSDN, Console.Read() returns an int, which is

> The next character from the input stream, or negative one (-1) if there are currently no more characters to be read.

try `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: Uhm, what if you check it so that you know for sure not guess?

Comment: either way, he needed to check that input and at that point in execution.

Answer (score 0):

Change your main method to this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int wgt = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Turtle's Weight: ");
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(line, out wgt)) {
            Turtle turt = new Turtle(wgt);
            Console.Write(turt.getWeight());
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("You must enter an integer.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPres Any Key To End");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

You were trying to read a string (the Console input) as an int. The method above will correctly cast the string to an int by parsing it. Notice the "out" keyword in the `TryParse()` method.

Answer (score 0):

change the lines 15 and 16 .

```
string wgt = Console.ReadLine();
Turtle turt = new Turtle(int.Parse(wgt));
```